# Quartiles as interaction term in regression analysis

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, fixed-effects-model, quantiles

Hello to everyone in this community. I am feeling like fish out of water writing in this community, but I know that I am at the right place.
Currently, I am conducting a research to assess the impact of Environmental, Social, and Governance factors on Return on Assets of the companies that are listed on London Stock Exchange. Beside the individual pillars of ESG, natural logarithm of market capitalization is included as control variable. The main idea is to test it with model like this:

ROA=β1*Environmental+β2*Social+β3*Governance+β4*SIZE+ε

I have done F-test, and Hausman test in order to conclude that fixed effects model would be the most appropriate for my dataset.
When I presented results to my mentor he said to me to add Quartiles (grouped based on market capitalization) in the model so that it looks like this:

ROA=β1*Environmental+β2*Social+β3*Governance+β4*SIZE+β5*Environmental*Quartile+β6*Social*Quartile+β7*Governance*Quartile+ε

However, what I don't understand in his demand is how should I implement Quartiles as one variable in my model in the way he has suggested because I would expect that Quartiles would be included as 4 dummy variables in a way like this:

ROA=β1*Environmental + β2*Social + β3*Governance + β4*SIZE + β5*Environmental*Q1 + β6*Social*Q1 + β7*Governance*Q1 + β8*Environmental*Q2 + β9*Social*Q2 + β10*Governance*Q2 + β11*Environmental*Q3 + β12*Social*Q3 + β13*Governance*Q3 + β12*Environmental*Q4 + β13*Social*Q4 + β14*Governance*Q4 + ε

Please if someone could help me to better understand what is expected from my to do. He said that it is expected that with including Quartiles variable SIZE variable would fall off. Any explanation would be greatly appreciated. Analysis is performed in R.

Comment: Why don't you stop by the office of your mentor and ask her/him for further expalantions? :-) ... just thinking out loud.

Comment: I wish. After she said to add Quartiles I wanted to ask for further explanation and I got "I have no time for you" and to "just finish it and send the whole paper the next time I hear back from you".

Comment: Alright, she means to investigate if the effect of explantory variable on ROA is changing across the distribution of explanatory variables. She is indeed expecting such a patter in this framework and hence has asked you to go after it. The point discussed in the answer by Peter Flom is along the same line. But I suppose your mentor does not like (or doesn not have time) to discuss openly about this :-/ an unfortunate situation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Then, in R I will input code to create three dummy variables (i.e. Q1, Q2, and Q3) and use Q4 as the reference group?

Comment: You should define dummy variables and add their interaction with the variables correspondingly, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

If you do what you have listed, you will have extreme colinearity and a model that is very hard to interpret. Including both quartiles and the continuous term is not going to be a good idea.

It is possible to use *just* the quartiles, although I don't advise it. Much better to use the continuous variable and use a spline to look for non-linear relationships.

Quartiles would (under most parameterizations) be three dummy variables with one as the reference group. However, if you create the quartiles, R will handle that for you, you don't have to program it yourself.

Also, while you have "interaction" in your title, I see nothing about interactions in your text.

Comment: Sir, thank you very much for your response. Firstly, I would apologize if the title of my text is not appropriate. Secondly, if I understand you correctly, my model would be like this, if I still proceed with using just the quartiles:

ROA=β1Environmental+β2Social+β3Governance+β4SIZE+β5Quartile+ε 

Sorry if that is not what you have meant. Don't wan to take much of your time.

And if that is what you have meant, then in my dataset I need to add another column called Quartile in which companies within my dataset would be assigned appropriate Quartile based on their market capitalization?

Comment: I would not put the continuous variable and the quartile in the same regression.